# Why hasn't Java's "new BigDecimal(double)" been deprecated?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

From [BigDecimal's constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-)

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
>
> The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:
>   writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which is exactly
>   equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally
>   recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this
>   one.
>
> When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that
>   this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the
>   same result as converting the double to a String using the
>   Double.toString(double) method and then using the BigDecimal(String)
>   constructor. To get that result, use the static valueOf(double)
>   method.

So why don't they just deprecate it and change the functionality to that of valueOf(double)?  What's the point of the unpredictable value that gets created?

Comment: The term "unpredictable" is aimed at the inept programmer, not meant as a property of the actual code. The sentences following that "unpredictable" statement make that perfectly clear.

Comment: The question of deprecation has already been addressed, but the reason for not changing the constructor to use the functionality of `valueOf(double)` is that Java *never* changes the contract of a published API.  This is a good thing—programs should expect that the behavior upon which they rely will be the same behavior in future versions.

Comment: BigDecimal keeps numbers as Strings. If you have a bank account you want to withdraw exactly the same amount that you paid-in. Any other form of recording numbers enforces conversion from decimal to binary system which means, many numbers would have infinite decimal expansion and hence, would have to be rounded.

Comment: @Joanna: No, BigDecimal keeps numbers as a BigInteger or as a single long (depends on the number of significant bits). BigIntegers keep their numbers as arrays of integers. Strings are not used, internally. They are only used to initialize a BigDecimal to a value that exactly represents the string representation.

Comment: What they are saying is that the conversion from the text representation (double literal) `0.1` to `double` is not exact. The conversion from `double` to `BigDecimal` is exact. But people who don't know this might think that a BigDecimal initialized with a double literal will exactly contain `0.1`, which is not the case, since the resulting `double` does not exactly contain `0.1`.

Comment: Thanks @RudyVelthuis, that makes more sense.

Comment: A string is an array of ascii symbols represented as integers

Answer (score 5):

It's entirely predictable. You get back exactly the value offered in the constructor argument. For the double literal `0.1` "the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to `0.1`", as you cited. The constructor faithfully picks up the value that's passed in. Predictably.

Comment: It is very, very useful for studying floating point behavior.

Comment: Are you disputing or reinterpreting the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

This program illustrates a practical use of the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor. The objective is to display the range of exact results that would round to a given double. It depends on being able to obtain a BigDecimal with the exact value of a double.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(range(1.0));
    System.out.println(range(Math.nextUp(1.0)));
    System.out.println(range(Math.PI));
  }

  private static String range(double d){
    BigDecimal down = new BigDecimal(Math.nextDown(d));
    BigDecimal up = new BigDecimal(Math.nextUp(d));
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    BigDecimal halfUp = midPoint(bd, up);
    BigDecimal halfDown = midPoint(down, bd);
    Boolean isEven = (Double.doubleToLongBits(d) & 1) == 0;
    if(isEven){
      return "[" + halfDown + "," + halfUp + "]";
    } else {
      return "(" + halfDown + "," + halfUp + ")";      
    }
  }

  private static BigDecimal midPoint(BigDecimal low, BigDecimal high){
    return low.add(high).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));
  }
}
```